# Problema con backdrop-filter: blur en iOS

Tags: html, css, web, design, blur

Estoy armando mi primera web y para la navbar utilicé la propiedad backdrop-filter: blur(8px). En todos los dispositivos se ve correctamente, a excepción de los que cuentan con iOS. Incluso se ve bien al utilizar el simulador de dispositivos de los navegadores desde la función de inspeccionar.

El código HTML es el siguiente:

```
    <header id="Inicio">
        <nav class="menu" id="menu">
            <div class="menu-arealogo">
                <a href="#Inicio" class="menu-logo-contenedor"><img class="menu-logo" src="Logos/Logotipo.svg" id="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-boton" id="menu-boton"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-botonicono"></i></div>
            <ul class="menu-arealinks" data-visible="false" id="menu-elemento">
                <li class="menu-links"><a href="#Inicio" id="link-inicio">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="menu-links"><a href="#Informacion" id="link-informacion">Información</a></li>
                <li class="menu-links"><a href="#Seccion-videos" id="link-videos">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="menu-links"><a href="#Contacto" id="link-contacto">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Y el respectivo CSS:

```
header {
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.menu {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu::before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Verifiqué en la web de https://caniuse.com/ y según la misma la propiedad es compatible en el explorador que mas suele utilizarse en iOS (Safari iOS)

Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: la verasion en la que tas ejecutando el codigo es mayor o igual a 9!

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como se ha indicado y como comentas que en todos los navegadores se ve bien salvo en Safari concretamente para iOS da que pensar que la versión que tengas de este navegador debe ser inferior a la versión 9 (a partir de la cual se puede usar esta regla CSS).
Esto se puede revisar en https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter

Comment: Gracias! La versión que uso es la última pero aún así no funcionaba. El problema era como escribía esa propiedad. En lugar de `backdrop-filter: blur(8px)` debía utilizar `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px)`.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de buscar varias semanas el error y después de hacer la pregunta, al volver a revisar https://caniuse.com/ , entendí que la solución era usar la propiedad `backdrop-filter: blur(8px)` como `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px)`.

Gracias a todos por su tiempo!

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.